# what decision tree algorithms is used for Random forest classifier in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

As in title i was wondering where i can check which decision tree algorithms is used by RandomForestClassifier in scikit-learn. It says in attributes `base_estimator_ = DecisionTreeClassifier`, then behind DecisionTreeClassifier in scikitlearn is CART so is it my answer?

link to scikit-learn [RandomForest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit-learn uses an optimized version of **CART** by default (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart).

It constructs trees by 'using the feature and threshold that yield the largest information gain'. The function to measure the quality of the split (a.k.a. largest information gain) in the trees can be set using the `criterion` parameter in the **RandomForestClassifier**.

The default function is the `gini impurity`, but you can also select `entropy`. In practice these two are quite similar, but you can find more information here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10228/when-should-i-use-gini-impurity-as-opposed-to-information-gain-entropy